# How to add a collapsible div in magento CMS block

Tags: magento-1.8

I added the new cms->staticblock to add charts in admin and I want to add collapsible div as if the titile is BMI+ if I click on + it has to show the image.Please anyone help me and solve my problem.

In chart.phtml

```
 <div>
<section>
    <?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('chart')->toHtml(); ?>
</section>
</div>
```

Comment: This makes no sense. Where is the script? please put all code related to this if you are searching for solution.

Comment: I added the total code.Please check it and suggest me

Comment: Its very simple. Add a specific class and write on click.

Comment: use : http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/eff_toggle.asp

Comment: @Mouni There is no javascript for making the element collapsable, please write the necessary javascript code.

Comment: We can write this code in cms static block does it works.If it works can u please change my code.

Comment: yes. ofcourse. Just add like the URL i forwarded you. Its simple. Write by your own. Thanks. Best of luck.

Comment: Yes,I tried but it is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are working examples using either pure javascript or for completeness jquery if it is available.

**EXPAND THIS JAVASCRIPT ONLY**

***HTML***

```
<h1  class="expand">EXPAND THIS JAVASCRIPT ONLY<a id="expand" href="javascript:expand('expand-content','expand');" >+</a></h1><div id="expand-content" style="display: none;"><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/de/thumb/1/11/Test-Logo.svg/783px-Test-Logo.svg.png" width="100%">Ut admodum praesent vituperata qui. Te semper scaevola pertinacia nam, et quis erant scriptorem est, ex quo quis tacimates. Te vix antiopam iracundia, laoreet referrentur delicatissimi per te. Nam ut conceptam ullamcorper, ad qui unum movet. Vim epicurei singulis perpetua ea.</div>
```

***JAVASCRIPT***

```
function expand(showHideDiv, switchTextDiv) {
var ele = document.getElementById(showHideDiv);
var text = document.getElementById(switchTextDiv);
if(ele.style.display == "block") {
        ele.style.display = "none";
    text.innerHTML = "+";
}
else {
    ele.style.display = "block";
    text.innerHTML = "-";
}
}
```

**EXPAND THIS JQUERY**

***HTML***

```
<h1  class="expand">EXPAND THIS <span style="cursor: pointer;">+</span></h1><div class="expand-content" style="display: none;"><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/de/thumb/1/11/Test-Logo.svg/783px-Test-Logo.svg.png" width="100%">Ut admodum praesent vituperata qui. Te semper scaevola pertinacia nam, et quis erant scriptorem est, ex quo quis tacimates. Te vix antiopam iracundia, laoreet referrentur delicatissimi per te. Nam ut conceptam ullamcorper, ad qui unum movet. Vim epicurei singulis perpetua ea.</div>
```

***JQUERY***

```
<script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
jQuery(function($){
$(".short-description").on("click", ".expand",function() {
    if ($(this).next(".expand-content").is(":hidden")) {
        $(this).next(".expand-content").slideDown("slow");
        $(this).children('span').text('-');
    } else {
        $(this).next(".expand-content").slideUp("slow");
        $(this).children('span').text('+');
}
});
});
// ]]></script>
```

The script functions I placed in footer.phtml.

You can see both examples working here http://dev.gaiterjones.com/magento/lets-get-ready-to-bundle.html

Comment: can we use in javascript for my theme there is no jquery enable.Please help me by using javascript

Comment: @Mouni updated my answer to include javascript only version, both examples are working on my dev site, link above.

Comment: How I need to add another one in html for BMR.Can you please suggest me.

Comment: It is working for only one.I want to add more like taht as in html but it is not working when I add another one.Please suggest me.

Comment: @mouni just create your expandable content element with unique ID's i.e. id="expand-one" for the first, id="expand-two" for the second etc. Then reference the id in the link a element for each expandable link <a id="expand-one".... <a id="expand-two". You do not need to duplicate the javascript.

Comment: Ok thank you.I got it and thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

You can try below sample code :

```
<div onclick="toggle_visibility('hideMe')">
<?php echo 'Click me to toggle'; ?>
<section id="hideMe">
    <?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('tables-charts')->toHtml(); ?>
</section>
</div>
<script type='text/javascript'>
function toggle_visibility(id) 
{
    var e = document.getElementById(id);
    if (e.style.display == 'block' || e.style.display=='')
    {
        e.style.display = 'none';
    }
    else 
    {
        e.style.display = 'block';
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: For one image it is ok.But I need to add More images as Ex:I f I click on BMI it has to show related image and if I click BMR it has to show related image.How I can modify please suggest me.

Comment: @Mouni Add onclick="toggle_visibility('UNIQUE_ID') to each and every text (BMI, BMR, etc) with unique id

Comment: Can you please change my code.So,that I can understand clearly

Comment: @Mouni I have edited your code only.

Comment: the title should be BMI and if I click only + it has to show image.Can we modify like that

Comment: @Mouni Please go through some javascript tutorials (like http://www.tutorialspoint.com/javascript/) and then you will understand the things better.